# What will be the depth that water can sink to the ground?

Tags: soil-science

Currently there is a pond in one acre of land which is of 4 feet depth. If the pond is filled with water it is expected that some percent of the water will be absorbed by the ground under the pond. To what depth will the water will be absorbed by the ground? The type of soil is clay type.

The reason for asking the question is, there is a shrimp pond which is infected with a virus and it has been observed that in next few days the adjacent pond is infected with the virus and like that whole area is infected which is causing huge loss for the farmers. We are looking for the option to restrict the transmit of water from the adjacent ponds by placing a plastic/HDPE boundary kind of the thing for x feet depth so that our pond water doesn't get make contact with adjacent pond's water.

I am interested to know the depth water can sink to the ground, to ask my query in a different way.. take a 4 ft dry pond and let's assume water is fully filled and the pond is kept ideal for a week. After a week how much depth the water would have sinked, can it be 20 ft or 30 ft or 40 ft or..?

Comment: This isn't earth science but common sense. You'll have to shroud the whole infected pond to effectively isolate it and then start your treatment. You will also need separate and isolated means for water and nutrient supply. Ask in biology for how long the virus survives in the soil.

Comment: @Fred OP posted the same question twice. You've linked to the other post, which has been closed without an answer.

Comment: @Spencer: I marked this question for closure because it was a duplicate, despite the other question having been closed. This question is exactly the same as the closed question. The comment you are responding to was automatically made when I initiated the closure of this question.

Comment: Are the two ponds at the same altitude? how deep is the other pond?

Comment: You need a professional soil scientist to examine the problem on site. This is not something that can be answered here. Because this has health and economic implications, I urge people to not answer this question, and I vote to close it.

Answer (score 0):

One quick and dirty solution may be to lower the virus-pond level and raise the new-pond level ... so the flow should be from the new-pond to the virus-pond.

Soil being clay may mean the flow is happening below the soil ... if the virus-pond is in contact with the unit below the clay you may already have widespread contamination.

Comment: I will be interested to know the depth water will sink or absorbed to the ground. For example, I have an empty dry pond of 4 feet depth and if water is filled and left for a week, how long under the pond the water will sink. I don't think it will be 200 ft, it maybe 10 ft or 20 ft or some x value.. I am looking for that x value.

Comment: Water will infiltrate and reach the water table. Then it will move along with the groundwater.

Or, if the clay material is hydraulically isolated from the underlying units, the water will move along the clay formation.